# Backbone fetch is giving undefined response for file download

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, backbone.js, download

Backbone fetch in Model gives undefined response for file download API when file size is around 50 MB. It happens only in IE 9 not in other browsers

The API would return base64 string in the response. I know base 64 string would have 30% more size than actual. The same code works well for 16MB files. But its not working for 50MB. Is it due to response data has more size so backbone fetch is not able to get the response ?

Below is my code

```
fetch : function(options) {
  options.async = this.async;
  options.contentType = "application/json";

  var model = this;
  var success = options.success;
  options.success = function(resp) {
    console.log(resp == undefined);
    //Code logic with resp
  }

  var deferred = this.sync('create', this, options);
  deferred.fail(function(res) {
    if (res.status === 500) {
      eventChannel.trigger('app.serverError');
    } else if (res.status === 404) {
      eventChannel.trigger('app.serverError');
    }
  });
  return deferred;

}
```

Here resp in options.success gives undefined. Couldn't get proper answer after lot of googling. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Please specify the version of IE you're using and also check microsofts support sites. Maybe it's a bug with IE.

Comment: Updated the version, IE 9+